# How can I add App Indexing concept in my Application?

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

Greetings of the day !! I have an Application which I am going to deploy on Google Play. Recently I came across App Indexing. I have a query regarding this. My Application is purely native and there is no any Web-View used  yes all the data are coming through dynamically fro web service. My Question is
**Can I add app indexing code into my Application Main Launcher class ?**
This is my Manifest. Where should i paste app indexing code ? please guide me.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.MyKidzDay" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".MyIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: you can do it in splash screen. or in any activity and you may do it in application class

Comment: @KhizarHayat thank you for your quick response. Should i make nay changes in my Splash.java class ??

Comment: hope you are following this https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app

Comment: yes I am following but One more questions.. Should I chamge my Splash.java or only pasting code in manifest would be sufficient

Comment: Please make it clear

Comment: you have to do both as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Indexing currently requires that the content on the app has a corresponding web page which is indexed by Google.

As mentioned by you, since there is no corresponding website for your app content, the regular app-indexing procedure won't work for you. You will have to first contact Google and let them know about your "app-only" content.

More information here - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/app-only

Comment: Ohh !! Thank you so much sir.. Means if my applications runs on web then I am able to use App Indexing. If my application is in Native then App indexing won't work.. But sir How can I make my application such a behaviour as App indexing application performs ?

Comment: Exactly. There is no direct way to index "app-only" content as of now. I did not quite understand your question though. Can you please reframe the sentence?

Comment: Sir I am new in Android so I don’t have much idea.. Let me try to explain you.. My application is built on native and there is no any web-view used for showing result.. In my Application all data is coming from web service. and then Parsing that data I am displaying facts. But My client told me that Yogendra Please use App Indexing concept to highlight application . after searching on net, i found that app indexing is only valid if my application is web based but My app is purely native.  Now suggest me , what should I have to do sir ?

Comment: You have two options - 1. Setup a website and let Google index it or 2. Fill that form in the url I gave. (but there is no guarantee that Google will accept it). I think you should tell your client these options

Comment: Okay SIr, Thank you so so much sir.. I filled all required fields in form and submitted to google.. Thank you again sir for clearing my doubts.. :)

Comment: This is stupid. I just found out about it and feel their marketing team would have been more honest calling it "Firebase Web-indexing for Apps"